# Ubuntu 16.04: Qt5 apps hasn't got global menu

Tags: unity, 16.04, appmenu, qt5

Some (or maybe all) Qt5 applications doesn't integrate with Unity's global menu.
I can provide two examples:

VirtualBox 5.1:
[image]

Wireshark:
[image]

I have got these appmenu related packages installed:

```
$ dpkg -l | grep appmenu
ii  appmenu-qt:amd64                            0.2.7+14.04.20140305-0ubuntu2                               amd64        application menu for Qt
ii  appmenu-qt5                                 0.3.0+16.04.20151130-0ubuntu1                               amd64        application menu for Qt5
ii  indicator-appmenu                           15.02.0+16.04.20151104-0ubuntu1                             amd64        Indicator for application menus.
```

I have got two Ubuntu 16.04 installations with the latest update and both experience the same issue.

Does anybody know how to fix this?